# Cancelling the coroutine in kotlin. Best practice to cooperative cancel

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, yield

I used yield() to help cancel coroutines as quickly as possible when asked to. I cannot use ensureActive() in suspend functions inside the coroutine.
I realized that by using yield() in loops, I slow down coroutine a lot. I am thinking about wrapping my suspend function in withContext(Dispatchers.Default){} so I can use ensureActive() instead of yield().
would this be good practice?

Answer (score 2):

You certainly don't want to force the use of the default Dispatcher for all your suspend functions.

But you can simply use the [`coroutineScope`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) builder to get access to a scope to call `ensureActive` on:

```kotlin
suspend fun asyncFun() = coroutineScope {
    for(i in 0..10) {
        ensureActive()
        println("Hello, world!!!")
    }
}
```